# Поглотить и проглотить - синонимы или паронимы?

Tags: синонимы

Поглотить и проглотить - синонимы или паронимы?

В словаре паронимов http://paronymonline.ru/%D0%9F/511:
поглотить
— 1. Принять, вобрать в себя. 2. перен. Целиком увлечь чем-либо. 3. перен. Потребовать много времени, затрат, усилий, энергии.
проглотить
— 1. Глотая, пропустить через глотку и пищевод. 2. перен. Смолчать, не ответить на оскорбление, на что-либо обидное, неприятное, злое (разг.). 3. перен. Сказать что-либо невнятно, не полностью произнеся слова, фразы (разг.). 4. перен. Быстро, жадно прочитать (разг.).
В словаре синонимов http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-58690.htm: 
среди синонимов слова *поглотить* - проглотить.

Поглотить критику. Что это означает? Можно ли так сказать?

Answer (score 2):

**Это паронимы, так как в речи они не заменяют друг друга:**
Море поглотило тонущий корабль. Проглотил на ходу стакан чаю.

ПОГЛОТИТЬ: **Приставка ПО** вносит зн. достижения **результата действия**: поглотить - принять, вобрать в себя. Сравнить: поблагодарить, погибнуть, подарить, познакомить, покраснеть, потонуть, поцеловать.

ПРОГЛОТИТЬ
**Приставка ПРО** указывает на перемещение кого-, чего-л. на какое-л. расстояние, преодоление какого-л. пространства: проглотить - это пропустить **через** пищевод, остальные значения переносные.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Поглотить*** и ***проглотить*** - синонимы или паронимы?

Оба слова  — **многозначные**. В большинстве своих значений эти слова не взаимозаменяемы и считаются **паронимами**.

В то же время у слова [***ПОГЛОТИТЬ***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) есть и такое значение: *съесть или выпить много или быстро.*

У слова ***[ПРОГЛОТИТЬ](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)***  — такое: *быстро съесть или выпить что-л.*

Вот в этом-то значении эти слова  и являются **синонимами**.

> ***Поглотить*** критику.  Можно ли так сказать?

Лучше  — ***проглотить*** критику.

См.:

> [**ПРОГЛОТИТЬ**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)
>
> <...>
>
> **3.** что. Разг. Выслушать или пережить без всякого протеста что-л. неприятное. ***П. оскорбление. П. насмешку.***